# jquery.localize doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have followed instructions found on https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize, and for testing purpose i have created this test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jquery.localize.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p rel="localize[greeting]">some text</p> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function(){
        $("[rel*=localize]").localize("test", "en")
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and test-en.json

```
{ "greeting": "welcome stranger.." }
```

locally it is working with IE8 and Firefox, but with chrome it is not working.
what i get is an error in console log:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/../test/examples/test-en.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

how can i set it up correctly?
are they any incompqtibilites with jquery 1.6.. or web browsers?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/../test/examples/test-en.json.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Sounds like you are running off your local harddrive. You really should be running a local server to test the files. Easy thing to run is [apache](http://www.apache.org/) or IIS [if on windows].

If you do not want to run a local server, you can set the flag in chrome to allow it `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: I have a deleted answer that stated this as well; hosting it on a server doesn't seem to fix it. (the page they were testing on was http://www.alfen.com.pl/c/test/).

Comment: now it is working. was my fault. after checking this online i made a typo. thanks for help